# Function built search with too much output

Tags: function, powershell, get-childitem

I will have a reoccurring search for strings in a defined file in a larger script.

```
function ConfigSearch([String] $path, [String] $pattern){
    [string]$path
    [string]$pattern
    Get-ChildItem -path $path | Select-String -pattern $pattern
}

ConfigSearch c:\smhost SMHOST
```

This is an example. Output will be

```
PS C:\Backup> C:\test\filesearch.ps1
c:\smhost
SMHOST

C:\smhost\smhost.conf:1:SMHOST = "D:\ca\webagent cr010\win64\config\smhost.conf"
```

I don't want anything else but `C:\smhost\smhost.conf:1:SMHOST = "D:\ca\webagent cr010\win64\config\smhost.conf"`. Or even more prefered `"D:\ca\webagent cr010\win64\config\smhost.conf"`, the content that I'm looking for.

---

Do you mean add them like this:

```
function ConfigSearch([String] $path, [String] $pattern){
    [string]$path
    [string]$pattern
    $Matches = Get-ChildItem -path $path | Select-String -pattern $pattern 
    $Matches | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
}
ConfigSearch c:\smhost SMHOST
```

One problem solved, but the output now is

```
c:\smhost
SMHOST
SMHOST = "D:\ca\webagent cr010\win64\config\smhost.conf"
```

And I don't want

```
c:\smhost
SMHOST
```

to be outputted.

Comment: What is the purpose of the first 2 lines of your function?

Comment: The whole purpose is that I will during a quite long script with alot of functions search for strings in different files that needs to be there. I want a function to call to have less code in total. And only the string outputed. Not the other two output lines I get.

Comment: So, since the first 2 lines apparently don't serve any actual purpose: why not remove them, as they are what's causing the undesired output?

Comment: Ok. I will do this when I'm back @ office tomorrow. I'm new to PowerShell and thought they had to be there as I built other functions in quite a simular way but without output like that.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're probably thinking of [parameter blocks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj554301.aspx), which look slightly similar, but have a `Param()` around the parameter definitions. However, you already defined the parameters right after the function name, so you don't need a nested parameter block. The 2 lines in your function simply cast the function arguments to strings and then write them to the success output stream. And since PowerShell functions return the entire uncaptured output on that stream, they end up being returned along with the result of `Select-String`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much for the quick help and good explaining, best forum I found in ages and never had such fast replys as here!

Answer (score 3):

`Select-String` returns a selection info object, you can select just the matched line if you want to:

```
$Match = Get-ChildItem -path $path | Select-String -pattern $pattern 
$Match | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
```